# Direct output to standard output and an output file simultaneously

Tags: shell, unix, file-io

I know that

```
./executable &>outputfile
```

will redirect the standard output and standard error to a file.  This is what I want, but I would also like the output to continue to be printed in the terminal.  What is the best way to do this?

Ok, here is my exact command: I have tried

```
./damp2Plan 10 | tee log.txt
```

and

```
./damp2Plan 10 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

where 10 is just an argument passed to main.  Neither work correctly.  The result is that the very first printf statement in the code does go to terminal and log.txt just fine, but none of the rest do.  I'm on [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin).

Comment: No, `cmd &> file` does not redirect to a file.  In *some* shells it does that, but in others is runs `cmd` in the background with no redirections and truncates file.  The behavior of `&>` is unspecified.

Comment: Is `./damp2Plan` still running after outputting one line, or is it finished? If it's still running, it's possible that `tee` has buffered later output. In that case you'll either need to write more output, or wait for `./damp2Plan` to finish.

Comment: @craig65535 Yes, I believe ./damp2Plan is still running as it is continuing to print output to its other files as it should.  What do you mean by "write more output"?  I'd rather not wait for it to finish since it takes around 10 minutes.  At this point I'm thinking it might be easier just to put in an fprintf to go with each printf.

Comment: @whatsherface I mean tee outputs in chunks. If your program isn't generating much output, tee might be waiting for its buffer to be full before writing to stdout and the file. Your program has its own output buffer as well - a printf won't be output immediately unless you flush stdout afterwards.

Comment: If you want closer to real-time output, you could just redirect to a file, and monitor it with `tail -f` in a different shell. I amended my answer to suggest that.

Comment: Can you try `./executable 2>&1 | unbuffer -p | tee outputfile` ? `unbuffer` is from `expect`, and simulates a terminal so the connected program line-buffers instead of block-buffering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tee`:

`./executable 2>&1 | tee outputfile`

`tee` outputs in chunks and there may be some delay before you see any output. If you want closer to real-time output, you could redirect to a file as you are now, and monitor it with `tail -f` in a different shell:

`./executable 2>&1 > outputfile`

`tail -f outputfile`

Comment: @craige65535 I guess it's not really important for the log file to update in real time. I really only want the terminal output to continue real-time (it prints output every few thousand times through a loop).  When the program finishes, can I then just grab everything from the terminal and stick it in a file?

Comment: Not sure how to automate that. You could run your program in a `screen` session, and after the program finishes, dump the scroll buffer into a file with `Ctrl-A :hardcopy -h outputfile`. That's still not quite what you need, though.

Comment: Ya, so I guess what is happening is when I use tee, everything is just sitting in the buffer? and nothing is showing up in the terminal (except the first statement which is getting user input) or the output file.  Using tail -f would totally work if there was anything in the file to look at.  I installed screen and am messing with it though. I'm sure I'll figure something out eventually.  Thanks for all the help!